# Both success and error Parse.User callbacks called on Parse.User.save()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

I believe it is a bug, but maybe someone already encountered it and found a workaround.

Here is my code :

```
console.log("Calling callback : ", p.state);

p.user.save({
  success:  self.av_callback("success"), 
  error:    self.av_callback("error")
});


[...]


// Address Verification Callback
av_callback : function(status) {
  console.log(status);
}
```

And here is the puzzling console output :

[image]

So it seems both callbacks are called. I tried using the promise synthax but the result is the same.

Does anyone has a suggestion as to why I am facing this strange behaviour? 
Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callbacks are executed when save method are called and doesn't wait until request is done.
Try something like this

```
console.log("Calling callback : ", p.state);

p.user.save({
 success:  self.av_callback("success"), 
 error:    self.av_callback("error")
});

av_callback : function(status) {
 return function(status) {
  console.log(status);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked and lead me to realise there was an issue with the way I was building my function. I fixed it, so now the code is fairly different, but works! 

Could you explain a little bit more why the callback was called twice, and how passing instances of the function solves it?

Comment: Well, this is how javascript works. You have defined object with functions and used () for invoking those functions.

Comment: He he, how was I not seeing this?! It seems obvious now, of course. Some code refactoring must have lead to me trying to use this function as a callback, and then the brain obviously shut down for a few hours... 

Thanks